# broken logo image when importing from json file in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am in the process of importing an svg image which path is in a json file. Below is part of the json file:

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "company": "Photosnap",
  "logo": "./images/photosnap.svg",
  "new": true,
  "featured": true,
  "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
  "role": "Frontend",
  "level": "Senior",
  "postedAt": "1d ago",
  "contract": "Full Time",
  "location": "USA Only",
  "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]
},
{
```

I have created two components. As the app is showing a list of jobs.  So the I have a job list component and a job card component.
The code for the job listing component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

import './job-listing.styles.css';
import JobCard from '../job-card/job-card.component.jsx/job-card.component';
import { Component } from 'react';


class JobListing extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        jobs: []
    }
   };

   componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({jobs: data}))

}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.jobs.map(({id, ...otherJobProps}) =>(
            <JobCard key={id} {...otherJobProps} />
            ))}
        </div>

       )
     }
   }

  export default JobListing;
```

and for the Job Card component is below:

```
import React from 'react';

import './job-card.styles.css';

const JobCard = ({company, position, postedAt, contract, location, logo }) => (
<div className='card'>
<img src={logo} alt="logo" width="42" height="42"></img>
<h2>{company}</h2>
<h1>{position}</h1>
<div className='details'>
    <h3>{postedAt} &#183;</h3>
    <h3>{contract} &#183;</h3>
    <h3>{location}</h3>
 </div>
</div>
)
```

export default JobCard;
At the moment this is what I get [image: the broken image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? If so, are your images in the `public` folder?

Comment: Thank you Alexander. Can you write that as an answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `create-react-app` you will want to put static assets such as images (if you are not not ES6 `import`ing images into the code) in the [public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder). Try moving these images into the `public` folder created by `create-react-app`. You may also need to update the paths. Assuming your structure is:

```
public
  images
    photosnap.svg
```

You may need to change:

```
"logo": "./images/photosnap.svg",
```

to:

```
"logo": "/images/photosnap.svg",
```

Hopefully that helps!